# Wedge product equals 0 implies linear dependence of 1-forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Why is it the case that, if $v$ and $w$ are differential 1-forms in $\Bbb R^2$, then if $v \wedge w = 0$ then $v = cw$ for some $c \in \Bbb R$? The converse seems straightforward enough, but I couldn't figure out a way to prove this statement. Does it depend on the alternating nature of the wedge product?

Comment: This is not true that $v=cw$. The correct statement is that v, w is linearly dependent.

Comment: Hint: calculate the wedge product directly. You will see a determinant showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differential 1-forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written
$$v= f_1 dx + g_1 dy, w = f_2 dx + g_2 dy$$
Where $f_i, g_i$ are smooth functions. Therefore,
$$v \wedge w = 0 \iff f_1 g_2 \cdot dx \wedge dy + g_1 f_2 \cdot dy \wedge dx = 0\iff f_1 g_2 - f_2 g_1 = 0$$
In particular, the wedge is $0$ iff the two forms are linearly dependent (since this is merely the determinant 0 condition).

Comment: Thank you! Arctic Char brought up the point that $v = cw$ is a stronger condition than linear independence. Is the former condition true?

Comment: When you say two differential forms are linearly dependent, how do you nean by that?

Comment: I was confused what you meant when you said there was a difference between $v = cw$ and $v$ and $w$ being linearly independent. Could you clarify?

Comment: From the condition $f_1 g_2 = f_2 g_1$, we know that at every point $p$, $(f_1(p), g_1(p)),(f_2(p), g_2 (p))$ are linearly-dependent vectors. In the plane this means they are scalar multiples of each other. However, we could have that $v = c(x,y) \cdot w$ where $c: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is any smooth function, so the constant doesn't need to be global.